# "SignatureError: Failed to verify signature" - Okta, pySAML2

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, saml-2.0, okta

For three days, I have been pulling my hair out trying to wrap my head around Okta & SAML.

On my local machine (OSX Mavericks), I am able to successfully follow the steps listed here: http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/pysaml2

*Things work.*

But moving everything over to our production server, which is a CentOS box, running nearly identical code, I am faced with this "SignatureError: Failed to verify signature" error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   auth_response = saml_client.parse_authn_request_response(SAMLResponse, entity.BINDING_HTTP_POST)
>       File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/saml2/client_base.py\", line 599, in parse_authn_request_response binding, **kwargs)
>
> response = response.loads(xmlstr, False, origxml=origxml)
>       File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/saml2/response.py\", line 510, in loads self._loads(xmldata, decode, origxml)
>
> File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/saml2/response.py\", line 335, in _loads **args)
>       File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/saml2/sigver.py\", line 1756, in correctly_signed_response
>           class_name(response), origdoc)
>
> File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages/saml2/sigver.py\", line 1571, in _check_signature
>     raise SignatureError(\"Failed to verify signature\")
>     **SignatureError: Failed to verify signature**

I have scoured the internet looking for a way to troubleshoot this error. I am new to SAML and Okta.

My assumption is that this has something to do with xmlsec1 acting differently on our production machine. But the versions are identical. There are many dependencies so I'm not sure where the problem might be.

Has anyone ran into this error? Any thoughts on what I might be able to try?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is a little late, but in case someone else runs into this:

pysaml2 provides a lot of logging using python's built in logging, I defined a handler for saml2.sigver and that gave a lot of info. In those logs I found this:

```
Error: unable to load xmlsec-openssl library. Make sure that you have
this it installed, check shared libraries path (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
envornment variable or use "--crypto" option to specify different
crypto engine.
```

Turns out I needed to install xmlsec1-openssl.
Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with `xmlsec1` can be extremely frustrating!

The main thing that I suggest doing is [enabling debugging in PySAML2](http://pysaml2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/config.html?highlight=debug#debug), and/or [setting the PYSAML2_KEEP_XMLSEC_TMP environment variable](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/blob/fd7a4f694b137a92f2a8b7f502d51fc21e3528c7/src/saml2/sigver.py#L803-L806), and/or [manually enable this code path in sigver.py](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/blob/fd7a4f694b137a92f2a8b7f502d51fc21e3528c7/src/saml2/sigver.py#L973-L983) - the general idea is to get a look at `xmlsec1` command that PySAML2 is calling and have PySAML2 leave the temporary files around so that you can test the commands yourself.

As I recall, most of the issues that I've run into in the past involved PySAML2 not finding the `xmlsec1` binary. [The `get_xmlsec_binary()` function in sigver.py](https://github.com/rohe/pysaml2/blob/fd7a4f694b137a92f2a8b7f502d51fc21e3528c7/src/saml2/sigver.py#L178-L213) is responsible for finding the `xmlsec1` binary. I suggest that you take a look at the code in `get_xmlsec_binary()` and make sure that it is looking in the right places on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the operational system you will also need to install additional libraries.
In my case, I got the issue on a CentOS server, so I needed to install more 2 dependencies in addition to `xmlsec1`:

```
yum install libffi-devel xmlsec1 xmlsec1-openssl
```

This solved my problem.
You should also have a look on Okta's documentation. They have a guide on how to use `PySAML2` to add support for `Okta` (via `SAML`) to applications written in Python.

https://developer.okta.com/code/python/pysaml2/