# Problems while implementing SSO using Django SAML2 Auth and AzureAD

Tags: python, django, azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

The error the application throws is:

`ERROR:saml2.sigver:check_sig:`

`ERROR:saml2.response:correctly_signed_response: Failed to verify signature`

`ERROR:saml2.entity:Signature Error: Failed to verify signature`

`ERROR:saml2.client_base:XML parse error: Failed to verify signature`

And it seems to be a Windows problem. Does anyone know how should I implement this? The command used to verify the XML is:

`C:\Windows\xmlsec1.exe --verify --enabled-reference-uris empty,same-doc --enabled-key-data raw-x509-cert --pubkey-cert-pem C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp8wssc6_f.pem --id-attr:ID urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:Assertion --node-id _579304c7-f1c4-5918-83ee-4b33c5df1e00 --output C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpw9lbnowc.xml C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcg9l7jik.xml`

And it returns `b""`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check  references [this](https://pypi.org/project/xmlsec/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197350/signatureerror-failed-to-verify-signature-okta-pysaml2)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague.  It seems that you have sent an authenrequest and got a response and the application on your end is throwing the signature validation error.  If that is correct then you likely do not have the correct cacert from the identity provider defined in your application.

Questions about SAML and verifying XML signatures really need the original xml idealy in base64 so it is possible to try to check the signature.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may face this problem in the future: Windows OS (still don't know certainly if the problem is caused due an OS particularity, I couldn't test it in other environments), pysaml2, and django-saml2-auth don't handle self signed certificates very well. I could solve the problem by just forking `pysaml2/django-saml2-aut`h and passing downloaded cert-files from IdP (`.pem`) manually.